# Counting the number of concurrent entities in a panel data set in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set of patient visits to a doctor over the course of several years. The variables include patient id and visit date. I am interested in determining on any given day how many patients are still receiving treatment. I assume that the last visit by patients indicates that they are no longer receiving treatment.

Patients have different number of visits and different dates of visits. This also means that patients have different lengths of treatments. Below is a sample of my data:

```
index  patient_id   visit_date
0      01           2014-08-10
1      01           2014-08-12
2      01           2014-08-13
3      02           2014-08-12
4      02           2014-08-15
5      03           2014-08-13
6      03           2014-08-15
7      03           2014-08-16
```

Ideally, I would like the final data set to look like the following:

```
date         num_patients
2014-08-10   1
2014-08-11   1
2014-08-12   2
2014-08-13   3
2014-08-14   2
2014-08-15   2
2014-08-16   1
```

I am using pandas and have unsuccessfully tried to approach this problem using `reindex`. If I were using `Stata`, I would use `xtset` and `tsfill`, but I don't know the equivalent of these in pandas. I will note that my data set has over 300,000 observations over thousands of days, so an efficient solution would be appreciated.

I have been tearing out my hair and scouring stackoverflow trying to figure out the best way to solve my problem, and I would appreciate any help!

**EDITED 3/19/16**

I realized that I might not have been very clear about my final output. I am trying to get a count of how many patients are receiving treatment on a given day, even if they have not had an appointment on that day.

For instance, (see output table above) I would like the count of patients on 2014-08-13 to be 3 since Patients 1, 2, and 3 are all still receiving treatment. Patients 1 and 3 have actual visits that day, but Patient 2 does not. Patient 2 still counts, however, since she has not logged her final visit yet (on 2014-08-15), and this indicates that she is still in the middle of her treatment.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get the output you want, but I'm not sure how efficient it will be on a very large/sparse dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

str = '''patient_id   visit_date
01           2014-08-10
01           2014-08-12
01           2014-08-13
02           2014-08-12
02           2014-08-15
03           2014-08-13
03           2014-08-15
03           2014-08-16
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str), delim_whitespace=True)

df['visit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['visit_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('visit_date', drop=True)

# function to fill in the gaps for each patient
def fill_gaps(group):
    return group.asfreq(DateOffset(days=1))

filled_df = df.groupby('patient_id').apply(fill_gaps)
```

This is what filled_df looks like at this point:

```
                       patient_id
patient_id visit_date            
1          2014-08-10           1
           2014-08-11         NaN
           2014-08-12           1
           2014-08-13           1
2          2014-08-12           2
           2014-08-13         NaN
           2014-08-14         NaN
           2014-08-15           2
3          2014-08-13           3
           2014-08-14         NaN
           2014-08-15           3
           2014-08-16           3
```

The index has all the info that we need, so we drop the patient_id column and reset the index. At this point you can use any of the solutions @gauden mentions in his answer and see which one is fastest on your dataset.

```
filled_df = filled_df.drop('patient_id', axis=1)
filled_df = filled_df.reset_index()
filled_df = filled_df.set_index('visit_date')

final_df = filled_df.groupby(filled_df.index).size()
```

Now final_df looks like the final dataset from your original question:

```
visit_date
2014-08-10    1
2014-08-11    1
2014-08-12    2
2014-08-13    3
2014-08-14    2
2014-08-15    2
2014-08-16    1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Setting up

Set up your dataframe such that the `visit_date` is formatted as a pandas `datetime` object and used as the index. The `index` columns is dropped as it is redundant.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# Create DataFrame from the example data
data = '''index  patient_id   visit_date
0      01           2014-08-10
1      01           2014-08-12
2      01           2014-08-13
3      02           2014-08-12
4      02           2014-08-15
5      03           2014-08-13
6      03           2014-08-15
7      03           2014-08-16
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

# Remove the 'index' column; this is redundant
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)

# Convert 'visit_date' to datetime and set it as the index
df.visit_date = pd.to_datetime(df.visit_date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.set_index('visit_date', inplace=True, drop=True)

# Peek at the first five rows
print(df.head())
```

A glance at the DataFrame:

```
            patient_id
visit_date            
2014-08-10           1
2014-08-12           1
2014-08-13           1
2014-08-12           2
2014-08-15           2
```

Note that the `patient_id` has been converted into an integer. This has no bearing on the rest of the analysis as long as each id is unique.

## Analysis

### Using `resample`

Since this is now a [time series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html), pandas offers a simple way of counting the number of visits using `resample`:

```
# set bin size to 1 (D)ay and count
visits_count = df.resample('D').count()
print(visits_count)
```

Which outputs:

```
            patient_id
visit_date            
2014-08-10           1
2014-08-11           0
2014-08-12           2
2014-08-13           2
2014-08-14           0
2014-08-15           2
2014-08-16           1
```

### Using `groupby`

An efficient way of extracting counts is to group the data and apply a summary function to each group.

```
def count_visits(grp):
    count = grp.patient_id.size
    return count

visits_df = df.groupby(df.index).apply(count_visits)
print(visits_df)
```

Outputs a pandas Series:

```
visit_date
2014-08-10    1
2014-08-12    2
2014-08-13    2
2014-08-15    2
2014-08-16    1
```

### Using Aggregation

Alternatively, you can use the `agg` function to achieve a similar result.

```
import numpy as np

visits_df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(np.size)
print(visits_df)
```

Outputs a pandas DataFrame:

```
            patient_id
visit_date            
2014-08-10           1
2014-08-12           2
2014-08-13           2
2014-08-15           2
2014-08-16           1
```

## Read More

- The [docs on `resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)
- This tutorial on [pandas `groupby` and `agg`](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.1/cookbook/Chapter%204%20-%20Find%20out%20on%20which%20weekday%20people%20bike%20the%20most%20with%20groupby%20and%20aggregate.ipynb) will take you much further.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I did not know about resample, and I think this will be very helpful. The final output from your code is a little different than what I wanted (see original post). For example, is there a way that I can get 2014-08-13 to have a count of 3, not 2? Should be a count of 3 since technically Patients 1, 2, and 3 are receiving treatment (even though Patient 2 did not have a visit on 2014-08-13).

Comment: @Eric has just added the missing part to your expanded question. Your solution combines his and my answer. May I suggest you pick one for your solution and up vote the other? :)